Envelope of matrix
Defining the envelope of a matrix as $\{(i,j) : J_i(A) \leq j< i\}$ where $J_i(A) := min\{j: a_{i,j} \neq 0\}$
I think we have the following theorem (correct me if wrong):
Theorem:
Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ positive definite,and  $A = L^T T$ its cholesky decomposition, then for $j<i$ it holds: $$l_{i,j}=0 
\Rightarrow (i,j) \not\in env(A)$$
Why one should have that the indices $l_{i,j} \neq 0$ with $a_{i,j} = 0$ can only take place within the envelope of $A$?
Any help or reference would be appreciated.

in fact it seems false already on the all-ones $2\times 2$ matrix. Where did you take this theorem?

@Exodd Do you know the "correct" form?

the exact form should be $l_{i,j}=0$ when i $< j \wedge (i,j) \not\in env(A)$
